# Can't Open file binary in SharePoint.Client

Tags: development, document-library, file, .net

This bit of code works for me:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(@"/Shared%20Documents/Email%20Body.html");

var _stream = file.OpenBinaryStream();
```

The following line causes an error:  `StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_stream);`

> "The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.IO.StreamReader.StreamReader((System.IO.Stream)' has some
>   invalid arguments.'

I'm not sure what I'm doing differently from what I've done in the past and what I see in tutorials now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to get the value property (`OpenBinaryStream().Value`). That's what appears to be storing the actual stream. My memory is a little fuzzy, but I don't remember having to do that before.. 
Regardless, it works!